# (Dax/PowerBI) Calculate the difference of value change between 2 dates. (Help)

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization

In Power BI I am trying to display a card visual that shows the % change in inventory value between 2 dates that I select in an between date slicer. I isolated the dax measure to see where it could be going wrong.

First Issue: Only the starting date part of the measure works, so when I select 2 dates the starting date will show the inventory value for that date, but the ending date shows (Blank)

Second Issue: The starting value measure only works when I click on a column in my column chart, not when I use the slicer, so if I click February 2021 on the column chart it will show the correct value. If I only set the slicer say to February 2021 it will show the Inventory Value for the start of the dataset in January 2020.

Details: There are only data points for the 1st day of each month, so January 1st 2020 has an inventory value, February 1st 2020, etc...

- The column charts include inventory value over time by Warehouse Type.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Dax Measure:

```
Inventory Value % Change = 
VAR SelectedStartDate = FIRSTDATE('Dax_Calendar'[Date])
VAR SelectedEndDate = LASTDATE('Dax_Calendar'[Date])

VAR SelectedStoreType = SELECTEDVALUE('Warehouse_Classification'[WH Type], BLANK())

VAR StartInventoryValue =
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Inventory_History'[Value]),
        'Dax_Calendar'[Date] = SelectedStartDate,
        'Warehouse_Classification'[WH Type] = SelectedStoreType
    )

VAR EndInventoryValue =
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Inventory_History'[Value]),
        'Dax_Calendar'[Date] = SelectedEndDate,
        'Warehouse_Classification'[WH Type] = SelectedStoreType
    )

VAR InventoryValueChange = EndInventoryValue - StartInventoryValue

VAR PercentageChange =
    IF(
        ISBLANK(StartInventoryValue) || ISBLANK(EndInventoryValue) || StartInventoryValue = 0,
        BLANK(),
        DIVIDE(InventoryValueChange, ABS(StartInventoryValue))
    )

RETURN
    PercentageChange
```

I wrote a dax measure that I thought would allow me to populate the card visual with the % change in value between 2 dates that I select with a slicer. Instead, the enddate displays blank and the start date only displays the correct value if I click on a column in the column chart. Otherwise, it will display the inventory value for the first month of the dataset.